# Need to extract a part of an rpm package and ship it as separate package?

Tags: rpm

I am new to package building stuff and i have a basic question. I have a package which contains some set of tools (executables which can be run from command line). Now my task is to take one tool out of that package and create a new package out of that tool. How should i proceed? Any documentation or web links which can help a newbie like me who is at a basic level of understanding. I am using fedora 18 and i can clone my packages using git clone.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all files from the rpm using: `rpm2cpio <RPM file> | cpio -idmv`
If you have the RPMs' spec file, just edit it and remove all unnecessary stuff. If you need to build your spec file, you just need to read some docs on rpmbuild, its quite easy. Note that after you install the rpmbuild software you have a sample spec file you can modify to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using FPM with 'directory' as source. Just create your desired tree structure (with your tool in it) and make a package of it.

```
mkdir -p usr/bin/
cp /path/to/mytool usr/bin/
fpm -s dir -t rpm -n mytool -v 1.0 usr/
```

FPM is pretty cool. Check out the [docs](http://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)!

Answer (score 0):

You can also dump the contents of the RPM using cpio. Make a directory copy/move the rpm you with to extract in it and run the last command below.

```
mkdir test
cd test
rpm2cpio rpmname.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

This may help as well. If not it's still nice to know.